# Can I create a schema that validates both soap 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: soap, xsd

I need a schema that validates both soap 1.1 and 1.2
how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. The two versions have different namespaces (`http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` and `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`), respectively. A schema can only have a single target namespace.

It would be better if you obtained both schemas, and then set up a parser with a schema cache or a catalogue that will pick out the right schema given the namespace.